# Block disable but show in front page

Tags: 7, blocks

I installed a theme that come with different homepage style (homepage-2, homepage-3, etc..)

I configured a new homepage name as homepage-abc, then I set my Default front page to homepage-abc. (Configuration>Site Information)

When I checked the frontpage, it displays homepage-abc with frontpage layout.

I check these frontpage blocks, the blocks show in frontpage is disable.

Is there other place the theme author wrote a script that configure the combination blocks to define the frontpage?

Comment: What is the theme name and its link, without looking at theme how can anybody know, how that theme is working..:)

Comment: aloom drupal theme by drupalet.

Comment: That theme is not available on drupal.org. I did checked, otherwise I had a plan to install in my trial site and check your issue, generally I di this way, but this is private theme, so no chance to try..:(...Anyway, if your issue solved, that's great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using **context** to make the combination of blocks.

Admin>Structure>Context

Under Reactions, choose block and make combination.